# Join the result of two tables join with a third table?

Tags: sqlite, join

I have  three   tables

```
POS_ITEM (  have 4  columns [ITEM_col1,ITEM_col2,ITEM_col3,ITEM_col4]) 
POS_MAP  ( have  3  columns [MAP_col1, MAP_col2,MAP_col3])
POS_DIS  ( have  5  columns [DIS_col1,DIS_col2.DIS_col3,DIS_col4,DIS_col5])
```

I  have  to  perform a `left  outer  join`  from POS_ITEM to POS_MAP, which I've been able to do.  But now I have to join this result with a third table, POS_DIS.

I tried this

```
select  b.MAP_col2,a.ITEM_col1,a.ITEM_col2,a.ITEM_col3
FROM POS_ITEM  as b
left outer JOIN POS_MAP as a on a.ITEM_col1=b.MAP_col2 as h
left Outer JOIN POS_DIS  as d on  d.DIS_col1=h.MAP_col2 ;
```

but it isn't working.

I've tried this

```
(select  b.MAP_col2,a.ITEM_col1,a.ITEM_col2,a.ITEM_col3
 FROM POS_ITEM  as b
left outer JOIN POS_MAP as a on a.ITEM_col1=b.MAP_col2)   as h
left Outer JOIN POS_DIS  as d on  d.DIS_col1=h.MAP_col2 ;
```

But this fails saying that "(" is not  a  valid  character.

Is this not possible with Sqlite?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: How is it "not working"? What is the input data and expected/actual results?

Answer (score 1):

finally  cracked  it...the result  will be  appending...no need  to add  braces

```
select  b.MAP_col2,a.ITEM_col1,a.ITEM_col2,a.ITEM_col3
 FROM POS_ITEM  as b
left outer JOIN POS_MAP as a on a.ITEM_col1=b.MAP_col2
left Outer JOIN POS_DIS  as d on  d.DIS_col1=b.MAP_col2 ;
```